# TSql query for a customer/order summary across a date range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables: a Customer table and an Order table.  The Customer table has many columns but the two that are needed are Customer.Id, and Customer.Name.  Similarly the Order table also has many columns and again only three are needed: Order.Id and Order.OrderDate, Order.CustomerId.  I need to build a query that will give an order report by date for a given date range: DateStart through DateEnd.  Some of the days may have no orders and other days that do have orders, not all customers will have an order, and some customers may have more than one order.

Here's the data and the report that would be expected.

```
Customer Table
Customer.Id     Customer.Name
1               One
2               Two
3               Three

Order Table
Order.Id        Order.CustomerId        Order.OrderDate
1               1                       2019-01-01
2               1                       2019-01-01
3               1                       2019-01-02
4               3                       2019-01-02
5               3                       2019-01-04

Results
Customer.Id     Customer.Name           Order.OrderDate Count
1               One                     2019-01-01      2
2               Two                     2019-01-01      0
3               Three                   2019-01-01      0
1               One                     2019-01-02      1
2               Two                     2019-01-02      0
3               Three                   2019-01-02      1
1               One                     2019-01-03      0
2               Two                     2019-01-03      0
3               Three                   2019-01-03      0
1               One                     2019-01-04      0
2               Two                     2019-01-04      0
3               Three                   2019-01-04      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to somehow create a table that will contain all dates (for `'2019-01-03'` there is no orders). Then you can cross join to customer to create all combinations and count customer orders.

```
declare @minDate date = (select min(OrderDate) from [Order])
declare @maxDate date = (select max(OrderDate) from [Order])
declare @Date date = @minDate
create table #rangeOfDates (dat date)

while @Date <= @maxDate
begin 
    insert into #rangeOfDates values (@Date)
    set @Date = dateadd(day , 1, @Date)
end

select
     c.Id
    ,c.Name
    ,r.dat as OrderDate
    ,count(o.Id) as [Count]
from Customer as c
cross join #rangeOfDates as r
left join [Order] as o
 on c.Id = o.CustomerId
 and r.dat = o.OrderDate
group by  c.Id, c.Name, r.dat
order by  OrderDate, Id

Id  Name    OrderDate   Count
1   One   2019-01-01    2
2   Two   2019-01-01    0
3   Three 2019-01-01    0
1   One   2019-01-02    1
2   Two   2019-01-02    0
3   Three 2019-01-02    1
1   One   2019-01-03    0
2   Two   2019-01-03    0
3   Three 2019-01-03    0
1   One   2019-01-04    0
2   Two   2019-01-04    0
3   Three 2019-01-04    1
```

Ideally, it would be to have a table that contains all dates instead of do it on the fly and restrict it based on `@minDate` and `@maxDate`.

Comment: I was hoping that there was some way to get all the dates without needing a table of dates on its own but given that even a year's worth of data would only have 365 dates I guess it's not too bad.  Thanks.